# Magento 2 - Get simple products from grouped product

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, simple-product, grouped-products

How can I get all simple products which are assigned to a certain grouped product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Found the answer in this file:

**vendor\magento\module-grouped-product\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped.php**

```
public function getAssociatedProducts()
{
    return $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($this->getProduct());
}
```